# Click event in the modal window doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

In my application, when the session gets time out a modal window asking for a password gets dispalyed. When I click the submit button, the event doesn't get fired and It again triggers the session call.The screen gets properly redirected but the thing is I can't invoke any javascript function from the modal window. What will be the problem?

Comment: What does your click event looks like?

Comment: @MichaelKampmannRasmussen I use knockout to perform the event. For eg: self.submit=function(){ //Code here }

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: @ramiramilu: ya it displays that the click event function is not defined

Comment: Try like this - `data-bind="click: $root.submit"`, let me know what happens.

Comment: @ramiramilu: no it is not working. In my code i have wrote a onchange event for the taxtbox, even that is not getting fired. (refer the above view page)

Comment: As i can see from the code, the button for submitting the form have type = "submit" and on the same button you're doing click event binding. type="submit" which is browser/html functionality to submit the form have high priority over any binding. Try with removing type="submit" from the button.

Comment: @Haridarshan: whenever I click the button it doesn't get fired

Comment: So this is my confusion - you have `id="DetailsPopup"`, but in the rendered view, you have button which will invoke `self.Submit` on a different div. So why do you have to different divs?

Comment: @ramiramilu: id="DetailsPopup" is the id for the modal window whereas I define it in masterpage. and the below code is the separate view page for lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

most likely due to the fact that when you dynamically add an element you have to assign click event like this:

```
$("h2").on('click', 'p.test', function() {
     alert('you clicked a p.test element');
});
```

Need to see your code but its what i ran into a while back.  good luck.